# How does setTimeOut work with resize event listener?

Tags: javascript, event-handling, resize, dom-events, addeventlistener

From the Mozilla [site](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/resize) on `resize`, I don't understand the below example of how `resizeTimeout` is made to `null` inside the `setTimeout` function. What purpose does that serve? By declaring both `var resizeTimeout;` and then setting it to `null`, the conditional of `(!resizeTimeout)` will be true, so what difference does it make to set it to `null`?

```
(function() {

  window.addEventListener("resize", resizeThrottler, false);

  var resizeTimeout;
  function resizeThrottler() {
    // ignore resize events as long as an actualResizeHandler execution is in the queue
    if ( !resizeTimeout ) {
      resizeTimeout = setTimeout(function() {
        resizeTimeout = null;
        actualResizeHandler();

       // The actualResizeHandler will execute at a rate of 15fps
       }, 66);
    }
  }

  function actualResizeHandler() {
    // handle the resize event
    ...
  }

}());
```

Comment: The effect is that `resizeTimeout` starts off as null, after the first resize event, it gets a value and a timer is started, and while it has that value, any future resize events are ignored. Then when the timer is finished, the 'actual' handler is called and `resizeTimeout` goes back to null, so the next resize event will start the timer again.

Answer (score 2):

This is a common technique called "throttling," as the function name suggests. This makes it so the resize handler will only be called at most every 66 milliseconds.

If the user is resizing the window, it will keep firing that event and triggering the resizeThrottler function constantly. However, if you executed the actualResizeHandler every time the resize event was triggered, your page would get bogged down.

Since the resizeTimeout is being set to null WITHIN the timeout function, the expression `!resizeTimeout` will only be true at most every 66 milliseconds. Once those 66 milliseconds are up, you can set another one.